# Modify Time and Material table in field service task report

Tags: odoo, odoo-16

in field service I created new report by inheriting Task Report (industry_fsm.worksheet_custom_page) and I need to use time and material table in it. For now I used industry_fsm_sale.worksheet_time_and_material to call the table as I found it in original report documents but I need to edit it - I need to remove prices from it.

Odoo version 16.

Anyone knows where can I find this table or how can I access it?